# openssl crash on nginx building ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nginx, openssl

trying this on ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo ./configure --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx-zctdR4/nginx-1.18.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-zctdR4/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module
```

getting this src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:721:9: error: ‘ENGINE_by_id’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
721 |         engine = ENGINE_by_id((char *) p);
|         ^~~~~~

any solution?

Comment: That's just a deprecation warning, it is intended for developers and irrelevant as an end user. What exactly do you mean by `crash`?

Comment: it is not building the modules

Comment: nginx 1.18.0 is way out of date -- the [first versions to support OpenSSL 3 were dev 1.21.2](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) and stable 1.22.0